# Determine process (and user) that is creating packets to given IP

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

Given an external IP address and target port, in Linux, is there any way to use something like `ngrep` or `tcpdump` to identify the process and/or user that is sometimes sending traffic to it? Or `iptables` rules? Is there a recommended way to run an ongoing monitor that's not too resource intensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rich Alloway - RogueWave](https://serverfault.com/a/831691/301402)'s answer had some promising suggestions, but each package falls short in one way or another.  The only option I could find that satisfied all my needs was [sysdig](https://www.sysdig.org/)

There's many ways to use it, such as:

```
sysdig -p "*%evt.num %evt.datetime %evt.cpu (%user.name) %proc.name (%thread.tid) %evt.dir %evt.type %evt.info" '(fd.rnet=1.2.0.0/16 or fd.rnet=3.4.5.0/24) and fd.rport=443' | tee outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the IP and port, you can use `netstat` to find out which process/user is associated with the connection by using a few parameters:  `netstat -tunp`

```
# netstat -tunp
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0     36 192.168.42.253:22       10.0.0.7:51313          ESTABLISHED 4060/sshd: ralloway
```

The `-t` option turns on TCP.
The `-u` option turns on UDP.
The `-n` option turns on numeric printing of hosts, ports, etc.
The `-p` option turns on printing the PID and name of the program.

The `ss` utility is a newer replacement for `netstat` and, in this case, the same options return the same info:

```
# ss -tunp
Netid State      Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address:Port   Peer Address:Port              
tcp   ESTAB      0      0       192.168.42.253:22    10.0.0.7:51313               users:(("sshd",pid=4062,fd=3),("sshd",pid=4060,fd=3))
```

I'm don't know of any ongoing monitors, off the top of my head, but you could check out the options for iftop, nettop, nethogs, etc to see if they'll fit your needs.

-Rich Alloway (RogueWave)

Comment: It's not an ongoing connection. It's intermittent traffic. But thank you.

Comment: @chell Give nethogs a try.    It'll show you the PIDs and owners of the processes, the program name, network device used, and tx/rx data rate or cumulative amount continuously.

Comment: I read about it but it looked like it runs in a window I'd have to watch. I need something I can leave running and come back to see results later. I'll take another look to see if it has other modes of operation (or do you know?)

Comment: @chell nethogs has a trace mode that just outputs data to the console.  You could redirect that output to a file.